# Get server path with PHP

Tags: php

I need to a get a path to my file that looks like this:

```
 require_once '/home/domainname/public_html/somepath/myfile';
```

I want to make it dynamic, so that it works if I test on a different server. How do I get that part:

```
/home/domainname/public_html/
```

Comment: usually that'll be your `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Mark B

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/somepath/myfile';
```

Comment: and what if the current file is in some completely different directory? this is only applicable in very limited cases.

Comment: Using __DIR__ would exactly address the problem as in the question. The file was NOT in a different directory subtree.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are looking for is a wonderful PHP function called `dirname()`.

Use as follows for your current document:

`dirname(__file__);`

That will return the current folder you are in (for me as follows):

`Users/[me]/Documents/Development/Stackoverflow/37713165`